# CSS: How to set position absolute of a span inside a relative-position-div which contains

Tags: html, css, position

I have this code:

```
<br><br><br>
<div style="position: relative; background: #000000; height: 400px;">
    <span style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; display: block; background: #FF0000; width: 100px; height: 100px;">
    </span>
</div>
```

It works, all I need is the span is located by absolute position compare to the div container.

But when I add an image inside of the div:

```
<br><br><br>
<div style="position: relative; background: #000000; height: 400px;">
    <img src="FabledLeviathan.png">
    <span style="position: absolute: top: 0; left: 0; display: block; background: #FF0000; width: 100px; height: 100px;">
    </span>
</div>
```

The span does not display at [0, 0] comparing to the container div as it did before. It now displays under the image. How should I fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have  a small typo in the `<span>`'s style.

You have a `:` after the word `absolute`. Should be a `;`

```
<div style="position: relative; background: #000000; height: 400px;">
    <img src="FabledLeviathan.png">
    <span style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; display: block; background: #FF0000; width: 100px; height: 100px;">
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Eh6v8/ demonstrates the correct behavior after fixing this typo.

Comment: Oh so that was that typo which screwed up the whole script. Thank you.